# Reflect : Instantiate and throw exception from classname in string

Tags: java, reflection

I am using java Reflect in my Spring Batch project to create a generic `ItemProcessor`. I am currently stuck on how to throw an Exception from a class whose name is passed as an argument of this `ItemProcessor`.

In my code below, I manage to get the actual class from the String parameter, then get the needed constructor (with 1 argument). But when I want to instantiate the actual Exception (of the class passed as a parameter) and then throw it, I don't know how to declare the container of this exception.

Here's a sample of the code, the `???` are where I'm stuck :

```
String exceptionClass; // With getter/setter
String exceptionText;  // With getter/setter

Class<?> clazz;
Constructor<?> constructor;

try {
    // Get the Exception class
    clazz = Class.forName(exceptionClass);

    // Get the constructor of the Exception class with a String as a parameter
    constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);

    // Instantiate the exception from the constructor, with parameters
    ??? exception = clazz.cast(constructor.newInstance(new Object[] { exceptionText }));

    // Throw this exception
    throw exception;

} finally {
}
```

**EDIT**

One thing I might need to add is that I need the exception to be thrown with the exact class which was passed as an argument, since Spring Batch "Skip Mechanics" are based on the exceptions' classname.

Comment: what about generic exception? `Exception exception = (Exception ) clazz.cast(...)`

Comment: @user902383 If i use `Exception` directly, the exception thrown will not be caught later on by Spring Batch `<skippable-exception-class>`

Comment: That's not big enough picture. As you changed it to Exception, is there some code which catches it and transforms to RuntimeException with the cause? Or is this method and all above allowed to throw any Exception instance? It could be transformed by some proxy too...

Comment: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000 Yup, there could be tons of intermediate code between my Exception and the actual runtime (see : http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html). All I know is that if I throw the correct Exception, the whole mechanism works. I actually found a solution, I will post it immediatly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a working solution by explicitly specifiying that the `Class` object extends `Exception`. I can then throw it without needing to declare a new Object of this class.

```
// Get class of the exception (with explicit "extends Exception")
Class<? extends Exception>clazz = (Class<? extends Exception>) Class.forName(exceptionClass);

// Get the constructor of the Exception class with a String as a parameter
Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);

// Instantiate and throw immediatly the new Exception
throw clazz.cast(constructor.newInstance(new Object[] { exceptionText }));
```